# Determine the value for the constant c that makes the probability statement correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

$P(c \le |Z|) = 0.016$

where Z is normally distributed .

I know that this means that either $Z \ge c$ or $Z \le -c$, but I'm not sure how to use this to find the value of c.

Comment: where $Z$ is standard normal $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ ?

Comment: @ippiki-ookami correct

Comment: You want $c$ to be quantile 0.992 of the std normal dist'n. In R statistical software `qnorm` (without extra arguments) is the _inverse CDF_ or _quantile function_ of std. norm. In R, code `qnorm(.992)` returns $c = 2.408916.$ Then as in Answ (+1) of @callculus, the R code `2 - 2*pdf(c)` returns  0.016, where `pnorm` is _std norm CDF._ You can get $c$ correct to about two decimal places (i.e, 2.41) using printed normal tables. I think this is a drill problem on use of such tables; try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $Z$ is $\text{symmetric}$ around $0$, then $P(Z>c)=P(Z\leq -c)$, where $c>0$. These are the areas denoted by $4$ and $1$.

So you have to calculate $2\cdot P(Z>c)$. Using the converse probability it becomes

$$P(c \le |Z|))=2\cdot (1-P(Z\leq c))=2-2P(Z\leq c)=0.016$$

Since $Z$ is standard normal distributed we have $2-2\Phi( c)=0.016$

Now just solve for $c$.

## [image]

Comment: Nice presentation, except I think regions 1 and 4 should be smaller to fit this particular problem.

Comment: @BruceET It´s just a shematic illustration, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment continued:**

In the figure below, each of the two areas under the standard normal density curve
outside the vertical dotted lines (at about $\pm 2.41$) corresponds to probability 0.008.
So the total 'tail probability' is 0.016 as required.

[image]